Samples per Symbol of Baseband Modulations and Detectability
I am trying to evaluate the Bit Error Rate (BER) versus the probability of detection, $\mathbb{P}_d$  with an energy detector for several baseband modulations.
I am trying to understand the relationship the number of samples per symbol of a modulation in complex baseband with noise variance.
It seems that increasing the number of samples per symbol drastically lowers the detectability via energy detector.
Calculating Noise Variance
I calculate the noise variance (given an $\text{SNR}$) the following way:
$$N_0 = \sqrt{\frac{E_b}{2 \text{SNR}}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \text{SNR} n_b}\sum_{s_i\in s(t)}|s_i|^2}$$
Here, the bit energy $E_b$ is the total energy of the signal $s(t)$, divided by the number of bits, $n_b$:
$$E_b=\frac{1}{n_b}\sum_{s_i\in s(t)}|s_i|^2$$
I am evaluating baseband BPSK, and BPSK-CDMA, so the two symbols are $-1+0i$ and $+1+0i$.
BER
I achieve the theoretical BER with my BPSK receiver. However, it seems like the energy detector is highly sensitive to it.

Energy Detector
A detector takes a received signal $r(t)$, which is a list of complex numbers, and converts that signal into a single metric, $\lambda$, which is compared to a threshold value $\lambda_0$.
$$\mathcal{D}(r(t)) = \lambda \overset{H_0}{\underset{H_1}\lessgtr} \lambda_0$$
The energy detector threshold, $\lambda_0$, can be set with the following equation (however, I am finding the best threshold empirically, by using the Youden-J Index after logistic regression on AWGN-only signals and modulation+AWGN-noise signals).
$$\mathcal{D}(r(t)) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^n r(t)^2} \overset{H_0}{\underset{H_1}\lessgtr} N_0$$
We can assume that the Youden-J index is our Probability of Detection, $\mathbb{P}_D$.
Some Plots
The $\mathbb{P}_D$ (Youden-J) versus SNR plot shows that increasing the number of samples per symbol makes the signal less detectable.

You can see there is a constant $-3dB$ of "detectability" every time the number of samples per symbol is doubled. Here, the detectability of BPSK and CDMA are consistent, as both signals have the same energy.
Here are the PDFs the average energy of different signals. (This is the data that feeds the detector)


(Sorry these are hard to read, but SNR increases as you go down and to the right, so the lowest SNR is the top left corner, and the highest SNR is bottom right.)
The $H_0$ part is pure AWGN noise, sans signal.
The $H_1$ part is a BPSK signal plus AWGN noise.
You can see here that as the SNR goes up, there is more signal energy than noise energy, and it becomes easier to detect a signal.
You can also see that BPSK with one sample per symbol has less variance and greater separation then BPSK with 64 samples per symbol, where the average energy levels seem to be less distinguishable.
The Problem
Why does BPSK become less "detectable" as the number of samples per symbol increase?
Theoretically, if a detector is sampling at a higher rate (thus producing more samples per symbol) it should have a better, or at least par detection capacity as a detector sampling at a rate that produces only 1 baseband sample per symbol.
I think the problem has to do with the increased noise variance, $N_0$. If the number of samples of BPSK is increased, then $N_0$ must increase, because there is more energy.
So each individual sample is subject to this higher $N_0$ value, so the signal becomes buried in more noise.
Or is it that I'm calculating my noise variance incorrectly?
My code for generating these plots is here.

BPSK does not become less detectable as the number of samples increase if the noise density is not changed. If the received signal is filtered and sampled properly and above our designed minimum sensitivity, then the signal will be limited by the noise of the received signal and not our local quantization noise. If we sample that signal and noise properly (proper filtering, obey Nyquist), then our samples will accurately represent that signal and noise (independent of what rate we choose).
That said, the optimum receiver under condition of white noise (white within our Nyquist bandwidth), is to filter the BPSK signal with a matched filter prior to detection. That matched filter will optimally average (with a weighted average) all the samples within a symbol duration (and if a fixed point design, it's very important to let the filter grow the signal, meaning have more bits at the output of the filter than the input, such that the out of band noise within the Nyquist bandwidth is filtered prior to down-sampling to one sample per symbol).
